# Minimal Length of a regular Expression

Tags: regex, formal-languages

Working on my homework for a class and I came to this question:

For each of the following regular expressions, give minimal length strings that are
not in the language defined by the expression.

1. `(bb)*(aa)*b*`
2. `a*(bab)*∪b∪ab`

I'm going to try to only get help on the first one and see if i can figure out the second. Heres what I Know: Kleene * indicates 0 or more possible elements. and union of a set is the set containing all elements of set a and set b without repeating an element. Working through the first problem  starting by inserting lambda, i get:

1st run: bbaab
2nd: bbbbaabaabbaabbbbaab
3rd: bbbbbbaabaabbaabbbbaabaabbbbaabaabbaabbbbaabbbbbbaabaabbaabbbbaab

If I'm doing that correctly than strings of length 0 to 5 are not in the language. Am i doing this correctly?

Comment: Hint:  There are more letters than `a`, `b`, and `U`.

Comment: The first case can be a string of zero length. * means 0 or more occurrences, so in fact, if you use an empty string, it is also OK.

Comment: What do you mean there are more letters than a b and u? I realize that the string proceding the * can be any possible string, but in the minimal case, we would put the empty string λ in place of the *, so the first string generated would have to be bb[λ]aa[λ]λ right?

Comment: You'll probably have better luck asking this question on [cstheory.se].  The regexes we usually discuss here are not the theory-pure regular expressions you're talking about.

Comment: Alright its posted there. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Alan Moore: No, cstheory is for research-level questions (questions which are nontrivial to professors), not for homework. Please do not suggest it in those cases. Instead, math.stackexchange.com is suitable.

Answer (score 3):

The first regular expression is matching any word that starts with an even number of 'b's (zero included) followed by an even number of 'a's (zero is ok), then followed by some 'b's.

This means that the empty string is in the language, as well as the string "b".
However, the string "a" is not in the language.

Thus all the minimal length string that are not in the language is "a".

---

The second regex matches on "", "a" and "aa" (by a*(bab)*) and also on "b" and "ab".
However it doesn't match on "ba" and "bb".

Thus the minimal strings are of length 2: "bb" and "ba".

Comment: You misread it because OP didn't format it well. After edition, the regex is `(bb)*(aa)*b*` not `(bb)*aab`.

Comment: The second regex simplified is a*bab+b+ab, so this is a word that starts with some amount of a's, including 0, followed by bab* (which can also be the null string) so its possilbe the null string is in the language becase λ ∪ λ ∪ λ = λ.
I'm confused about what the union does though when the empty string is not used.  Why dont bb and ba work in the second one?